# Correct xpath for table data Scrapy

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from a table with the following html:

[image]

Sorry for loading as an image, when I try to paste the code it does not display correctly, but I am only interested in the text associated with the highlighted classes.

I have tried to work down the tree using, for example, `response.xpath('//table/tbody/td').extract()` which returns nothing. I have also tried accessing the classes like, for example, `response.xpath('//div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[class="pricePweek"]').extract()` but again this is returning nothing. Is it the line breaks which are casuing the problem here?

I haven't had this issues when using Scrapy before, but have not tried to scrape from a table structure like this.

Comment: Instead of pictures try to drop here a link containing the table elements so that you can have a quick response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that your are using Browser to validate your Xpath and then using them on Scrapy. Which may not give you a true picture. Consider the below html page

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="name">Tarun</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you save the HTML in a file and open in browser

[image: tbody added]

Can you see `tbody` added by the browser? This is not there in our source code. Which scrapy would see. So your xpath should not have `tbody` in it. If you use below it should work

```
price = response.xpath('//td[class="pricePweek"]').extract()
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I should follow the tree based on the html in the shell then! Thank you

Comment: Hi @Tarun Lalwani having a little trouble with another site, would you mind if I started a chat with you to get you opinion on it? Don't want to unnecessarily start another question.

Comment: Sure, you don't need to un-accept the answer for the same though :-)

Comment: Thanks! https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156517/room-for-maverick-and-tarun-lalwani

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain what kind of output you prefer. Assuming that your expected output is one item per row of the data table, and here is a sample code (you may need to remove the ipython console promptions):

```
In [10]: for tr in response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr'):
    ...:     item = dict()
    ...:     item['title'] = tr.xpath('./td[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
    ...:     item['description'] = ','.join(x.strip() for x in tr.xpath('./td[@class="description"]//text()').extract())
    ...:     item['pricePweek'] = tr.xpath('./td[@class="pricePweek"]//text()').extract_first().strip()
    ...:     item['weeks'] = tr.xpath('./td[@class="weeks"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
    ...:     item['bookFees'] = tr.xpath('./td[@class="bookFees"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
    ...:     item['total'] = tr.xpath('./td[@class="total"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
    ...:     item['sDate'] = tr.xpath('./td[@class="sDate"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
    ...:     item['bookLink'] = tr.xpath('./td[@class="bookLink"]/a/@href').extract_first().strip()
    ...:     print(item)
```

And here is the print:

```
{'title': 'En-Suite (Ground Floor)', 'description': '10.5sqm,3/4 bed,En-suite Bathroom (WC, Basin and Bath),Use of ground floor communal kitchen', 'pricePweek': '£163.00', 'weeks': '50', 'bookFees': '£250.00', 'total': '£8,150.00', 'sDate': '23 Sep 2017', 'bookLink': 'https://www.crm-students.com/crm-accommodation/application-form/?tx_wistcas_booknow%5BroomType%5D=2917&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bwait%5D=1&tx_wistcas_booknow%5BbookingPeriod%5D=5386&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Baction%5D=book0&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bcontroller%5D=RoomType&cHash=3dd0f1b377330cfbad6327b728678cbd'}
{'title': 'En-Suite (Ground Floor)', 'description': '10.5sqm,3/4 bed,En-suite Bathroom (WC, Basin and Bath),Use of ground floor communal kitchen', 'pricePweek': '£163.00', 'weeks': '49', 'bookFees': '£250.00', 'total': '£7,987.00', 'sDate': '30 Sep 2017', 'bookLink': 'https://www.crm-students.com/crm-accommodation/application-form/?tx_wistcas_booknow%5BroomType%5D=2917&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bwait%5D=1&tx_wistcas_booknow%5BbookingPeriod%5D=6075&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Baction%5D=book0&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bcontroller%5D=RoomType&cHash=db85ff90cacb487ee98942d955141b09'}
{'title': 'Large Studio (Courtyard)', 'description': '22-23m,2,3/4 bed,Generous studio with same features as "Standard" but slightly larger,Dual Occupancy is available for an additional 20% of the advertised rate per week', 'pricePweek': '£223.00', 'weeks': '51', 'bookFees': '£250.00', 'total': '£11,373.00', 'sDate': '16 Sep 2017', 'bookLink': 'https://www.crm-students.com/crm-accommodation/application-form/?tx_wistcas_booknow%5BroomType%5D=718&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bwait%5D=1&tx_wistcas_booknow%5BbookingPeriod%5D=5652&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Baction%5D=book0&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bcontroller%5D=RoomType&cHash=e959ccd71b62be9211eb1dd3ad5b362c'}
{'title': 'Large Studio (Courtyard)', 'description': '22-23m,2,3/4 bed,Generous studio with same features as "Standard" but slightly larger,Dual Occupancy is available for an additional 20% of the advertised rate per week', 'pricePweek': '£223.00', 'weeks': '49', 'bookFees': '£250.00', 'total': '£10,927.00', 'sDate': '30 Sep 2017', 'bookLink': 'https://www.crm-students.com/crm-accommodation/application-form/?tx_wistcas_booknow%5BroomType%5D=718&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bwait%5D=1&tx_wistcas_booknow%5BbookingPeriod%5D=6075&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Baction%5D=book0&tx_wistcas_booknow%5Bcontroller%5D=RoomType&cHash=5f798c129cfe56dead110ed5d80efa75'}
```

Note that since some cells contain other elements, you need handle them properly. For example, the description cell contains a unorder list, here I concatenate them by the seperation `,`.

Hope this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this!